# Net6. additionalProbingPaths in the runtimeconfig.json blocks probing framework dlls

Tags: c#, dll, deployment, .net-6.0

colleagues.

I'm doing a migration of complicated dll project from Net Framework to NET6.
Migration itself has been completed, but I have an issue with deployment: we prefer to put all dll to a subfolder ('lib' usually). In the Net Framework it worked very well via

But in the NET6 it's not available. But we have an alternative: file *.runtimeconfig.json and this file contains the option 'additionalProbingPaths'. Looks like that what we need.
But there are two problems with this file:

1. You can't just copy dlls into this folder and wait that it will work. No. You have to create very complicated directory structure related to nuget packages. Ok. It's possible to fix by editing the *.deps.json file. Then all dlls will be in one folder.
2. But second issue looks very strange:
   if we have additionalProbingPaths option into json then (I assume) ALL dll (include framwork dlls) are searching into these paths ONLY, not only third-part packages.

Log when probing is not work (additionalProbingPaths set to subfolder). Third-part libraries (Devexpress) are in the same folder where the dll is, ad they are loading, but framework dll are not loaded, because they are looked into lib subfolder only.

```
  Considering entry [DevExpress.Xpo/22.1.5/DevExpress.Xpo.v22.1.dll], probe dir [], probe fx level:0, entry fx level:0
    Local path query exists C:\projects\OnLIMS 76\Bin\DevExpress.Xpo.v22.1.dll
    Probed deps dir and matched 'C:\projects\OnLIMS 76\Bin\DevExpress.Xpo.v22.1.dll'
Processing TPA for deps entry [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, 2.0.0, lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll]
  Considering entry [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/2.0.0/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll], probe dir [], probe fx level:0, entry fx level:0
    Local path query did not exist C:\projects\OnLIMS 76\Bin\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
    Skipping... not found in deps dir 'C:\projects\OnLIMS 76\Bin\'
    Skipping... not found in probe dir ''
  Considering entry [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/2.0.0/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll], probe dir [C:\projects\OnLIMS 76\Bin\lib], probe fx level:-1, entry fx level:0
    Relative path query did not exist C:\projects\OnLIMS 76\Bin\lib\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection\2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
    Skipping... not found in probe dir 'C:\projects\OnLIMS 76\Bin\lib'
Warning:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (OnWshPlugin.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection', version: '2.0.0'
    path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll'
```

Log when everything works correct. Here is additionalProbingPaths is not present into the json file. Third-part libraries (Devexpress) are into the same folder with the main dll.
As we see it looks like framework dlls are into the dll working directory (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll, in this example), but they are not, of course.

```
Processing TPA for deps entry [DevExpress.Xpo, 22.1.5, DevExpress.Xpo.v22.1.dll]
  Considering entry [DevExpress.Xpo/22.1.5/DevExpress.Xpo.v22.1.dll], probe dir [], probe fx level:0, entry fx level:0
    Local path query C:\projects\OnLIMS 76\Bin\DevExpress.Xpo.v22.1.dll (skipped file existence check)
    Probed deps dir and matched 'C:\projects\OnLIMS 76\Bin\DevExpress.Xpo.v22.1.dll'
Processing TPA for deps entry [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, 2.0.0, lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll]
  Considering entry [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/2.0.0/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll], probe dir [], probe fx level:0, entry fx level:0
    Local path query C:\projects\OnLIMS 76\Bin\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll (skipped file existence check)
    Probed deps dir and matched 'C:\projects\OnLIMS 76\Bin\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll'
Adding tpa entry: C:\projects\OnLIMS 76\Bin\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll, AssemblyVersion: 2.0.0.0, FileVersion: 2.0.0.17205
```

I understand that issue is not typical and complicated, but, however, maybe somebody faced with this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: You may need to edit the csproj file with Notepad.  VS creates absolute paths to files starting with c:\.  I often edit the csproj and change the absolute path to relative paths.  When I debug a complicated project I often make backup of my code.  So I copy the root folder to a new location.  I usually put a date on the root folder.  Using absolute paths the copy does not work.  The compiler will take old folder and not new folder.

Answer (score 1):

So I have fixed this problem.

1. Remove *.deps.json file from your deployment folder. So Windows will not know where to resolve your assemblies.
2. Add to your C# code handler for this event AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve
3. And event handler

```
    private Assembly? CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object? sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Resolve {args.Name}");
            string RMSAssemblyFolder = "";

            Assembly? MyAssembly = null;
            string strTempAssmbPath = string.Empty;

            Assembly objExecutingAssemblies = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            AssemblyName[] arrReferencedAssmbNames = objExecutingAssemblies.GetReferencedAssemblies();

            AssemblyName? myAssemblyName = Array.Find(arrReferencedAssmbNames, a => a.Name == args.Name);

            if (myAssemblyName != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Load from references");
                MyAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(myAssemblyName.CodeBase);
            }
            else
            {
                var localPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\lib\devexpress22" ?? "";
                var dllName = args.Name.Split(",")[0] + ".dll";
                MessageBox.Show($"Local file: {Path.Combine(localPath, dllName)}");
                strTempAssmbPath = Path.Combine(localPath, dllName);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strTempAssmbPath))
                {
                    if (File.Exists(strTempAssmbPath))
                    {
                        // Loads the assembly from the specified path.                  
                        MyAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(strTempAssmbPath);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Returns the loaded assembly.
            return MyAssembly;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Main idea - you have to provide correct file name, then load assembly form this file and return it to the Windows.
That's all. Now you can locate your dlls anywhere. You can even point to different folders.

Comment: wow, finally some working method. thanks.
But i could not use it for my project references! it only worked for third party packages (from nuget, ...)